# Joining 2 temp tables and issue with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have such a situation. For some reason, when I join two temporary tables one column gets completely different results. Depending whether I group by LOC column from Actuals or Forecast, one of the column gives correct results and another one gets something totally weird.

The results are accurate for Actuals (1718789) but wrong for Forecast

```
WITH ACTUALS AS
(
  SELECT [LOC], [DMDUNIT], [DMDPostDate], 
  SUM(HistoryQuantity) AS 'Actuals'
  FROM SCPOMGR.HISTWIDE_CHAIN
  GROUP BY [LOC], [DMDUNIT], [DMDPostDate]    
),

Forecast AS
(
  SELECT [LOC], [DMDUNIT], [STARTDATE],
  SUM(TOTFCST) AS 'Forecast'
  FROM SCPOMGR.FCSTPERFSTATIC
  -- Forecast Albertsons 99484.136 (wrong: should be 122880.591)
  GROUP BY [LOC], [DMDUNIT], [STARTDATE]   
)
 SELECT A.[LOC],  SUM(A.Actuals) AS 'Actuals', SUM(F.Forecast) AS 'Forecast'
 FROM Actuals A FULL OUTER JOIN Forecast F 

  on A.[DMDUNIT] = F.[DMDUNIT] 
  AND f.[STARTDATE] = a.[DMDPostDate] 
  and a.[LOC] = f.[LOC]
    
  GROUP BY A.[LOC]
  ORDER BY A.[LOC]
```

When I change GROUP BY from A.[LOC] to F.[LOC] I have the reverse effect. Now my Actuals are correct, but Forecast is not.

Something is wrong with the GROUP BY. Depending if I GROUP BY a.[LOC] I get a correct result for 'Actuals' but incorrect for 'Forecast', if I GROUP BY f.[LOC] I get a correct result for 'Forecast', but incorrect for 'Actuals'.

```
WITH ACTUALS AS
(
  SELECT [LOC], [DMDUNIT], [DMDPostDate], 
  SUM(HistoryQuantity) AS 'Actuals'
  FROM SCPOMGR.HISTWIDE_CHAIN
  -- Actuals 80324 (Albertsons) grouped by F.[LOC] - incorrect (should be 1718789)
  GROUP BY [LOC], [DMDUNIT], [DMDPostDate]    
),

Forecast AS
(
  SELECT [LOC], [DMDUNIT], [STARTDATE],
  SUM(TOTFCST) AS 'Forecast'
  FROM SCPOMGR.FCSTPERFSTATIC
  -- Forecast Albertsons 122880.591 (Albertsons) grouped by f.[LOC] - correct
  GROUP BY [LOC], [DMDUNIT], [STARTDATE]   
)
 SELECT F.[LOC],  SUM(F.Forecast) AS 'Forecast', SUM(A.Actuals) AS 'Actuals'
 FROM Forecast F  FULL OUTER JOIN   Actuals A

  on F.[DMDUNIT] = A.[DMDUNIT] 
  AND F.[STARTDATE] = A.[DMDPostDate]
  and F.[LOC] = A.[LOC]


  GROUP BY F.[LOC]
  ORDER BY F.[LOC]
```

It is technically the same code just GROUP BY throws off the results of one of the columns.

Does someone know how it can be fixed.
I need to keep the JOIN on those 3 fields

```
  on A.[DMDUNIT] = F.[DMDUNIT] 
  AND f.[STARTDATE] = a.[DMDPostDate] 
  and a.[LOC] = f.[LOC]
```

Comment: Note - you should not 'quote' column aliases; use `[delimiters (only if) necessary]`, quotes are for 'string lliterals'

Comment: Help us help you and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem with sample data and the expected results.

Comment: "Totally wierd" is a very bad description of the issue. It doesn't seem like you've done any analysis of the issue at all. Anyway, I guess that your actuals and forecast are at different levels of detail, and you're having double counting issues. For example are your actuals daily and your forecast weekly or monthly? These are the basic pieces of information that you'll need to provide, let alone some actual sample data. Another piece of information to provide is that actual database platform. Is it SQL server?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid when I say "totally weird" I mean not what I expect.  Not sure what you don't like about my expression... I use SSMS (SQL server). The issue is GROUP BY clause when I select fields and later trying to group them. When I group by F.[LOC] i get my 'Forecast' table right, when by A.[LOC] I get my 'Actuals' right... So I was wondering if someone had such a situation...

Comment: Has anyone ever had a situation where their query returned unexpected data? Yes. Can anyone help? Not without more information. You'll need to post sample data. You'll also need to look at the "not right" data - is it an exact multiple of the number you expect? Lastly, please clarify: _are your actuals daily and your forecast weekly or monthly_? If you want to solve the issue you'll need to explain in more detail, and that includes posting sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a FULL OUTER JOIN, so I assume there will be unmatched rows between the two tables and LOC will sometimes be NULL in either table. Use COALESCE to get the value from either table when one is NULL.

```
WITH ACTUALS AS
(
  SELECT [LOC], [DMDUNIT], [DMDPostDate], 
  SUM(HistoryQuantity) AS 'Actuals'
  FROM SCPOMGR.HISTWIDE_CHAIN
  GROUP BY [LOC], [DMDUNIT], [DMDPostDate]    
),

Forecast AS
(
  SELECT [LOC], [DMDUNIT], [STARTDATE],
  SUM(TOTFCST) AS 'Forecast'
  FROM SCPOMGR.FCSTPERFSTATIC
  -- Forecast Albertsons 99484.136 (wrong: should be 122880.591)
  GROUP BY [LOC], [DMDUNIT], [STARTDATE]   
)
 SELECT COALESCE(a.[LOC], f.[LOC]) as LOC,  SUM(A.Actuals) AS 'Actuals', SUM(F.Forecast) AS 'Forecast'
 FROM Actuals A FULL OUTER JOIN Forecast F 

  on A.[DMDUNIT] = F.[DMDUNIT] 
  AND f.[STARTDATE] = a.[DMDPostDate] 
  and a.[LOC] = f.[LOC]
    
  GROUP BY COALESCE(a.[LOC], f.[LOC])
  ORDER BY LOC
```